# Multiple Select on Chrome on mobile/tablet only displays on one line

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I'm sure this can't be the first time it's been asked, but the only similar thing I could find was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486567/multiple-select-behavior-in-mobile-platform and it doesn't answer my question.

I have a select:

```
<select class="myClass" multiple="multiple" size="3" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This displays fine except on chrome on a mobile/tablet - where the size is ignored and it displays in one line. That is fine by me for general use, but I need to be able to show some chosen values in a disabled select (above) and in this case only the first selected option is shown, with no way to expand the select.

It displays fine on firefox on my tablet, displaying all the rows all the time.

Is there any way to make chrome follow this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiple select remains one line and there doesn't seem to be any way around this.

BUT the only problem with this was (as mentioned above) the disabled functionality.

By disabling the Options rather than the Select itself, you can still open up the Select and view the selected options, without being able to change any.